# Different Routing between app_dev.php app.php causing a "500 Internal Server Error" looking for DefaultController

Tags: symfony

When trying to use my demo app in a production environment, the "app.php" is creating a "500 Internal Server Error" when app_dev.php works fine.

From the logs, app.php is looking for a DefaultController. Is the existence of a "DefaultController" obligatory in production or is there separate routing that's defined?

I've gone backwards through the routing and nothing I can find makes reference to a Default route.

Comment: Did you define the routing in `routing.yml` or `routing_dev.yml`?

Comment: No, DefaultController is not required in production.

Answer (score 0):

You have to clean your cache.

`app/console cache:clear`

The routes in production environment will be re-generate.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set true the Production Environment in the app.php file:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false)
```

switch to

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true)
```

and as WouterJ say define you route in the routing.yml